# docker link resolves to localhost

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm stuck on a very strange docker problem that I've not encountered before. What I want to do is to use docker-compose to make my application available from the internet. It's currently running on a instance on DigitalOcean and I'm currently working with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    version: '2.2'
    services:
      mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.4
        volumes:
         - ./mongo:/data/db
        ports:
         - "27017"

      mongoadmin:  # web UI for mongo
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
         - "8081:8081"
        links:
         - "mongodb:mongo"
        environment:
         - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance
         - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=user
         - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=pass

      app:
        image: project/name:0.0.1
        volumes:
          - ./project:/usr/src/app
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        links:
          - "mongodb:mongodb"
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        command: ["npm", "start"]
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

`Mongoadmin` connects properly and is able to connect to the database, while the database itself cannot be connected to from outside the host.

The problem is that the app won't connect to the right address. It is a express server using mongoose to connect to the database. Before connecting I'm logging the url it will connect to. In my config.js I've listed `mongodb://mongodb/project`, but this is resolved to `localhost` thus resulting in `MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect`. The name of the container is resolved, but not to the proper address.

I've tried to connect to the IP (in the `172.18.0.0` range) that docker addressed to the container, but that also resolved to localhost. I've looked into /etc/hosts but this does not show anything related to this. Furthermore, I'm baffled because the mongo-express container is able to connect.

I've tried changing the name of the container, thinking it might be block for some reason due to previous runs or something like that, but this did not resolve the issue

I've tried both explicit `links` and implicit using dockers internal DNS resolve, but both did not work.

When binding port 27017 to localhost it is able to connect, but because of security and easy configuration via environment variables, I rather have the mongodb instance not bound to localhost.

I've also tried to run this on my local machine and that works as expected, being that both `mongoadmin` and `app` are able to connect to the `mongodb` container. My localmachine runs `Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802`, while the VPS runs on `Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72`, thus a newer version.

Could this be a newly introduced bug? Or am I missing something else? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose file seems not have linked the app and mongodb container.

You have this:

```
app:
        image: project/name:0.0.1
        volumes:
          - ./project:/usr/src/app
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        command: ["npm", "start"]
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

While I think it should be this:

```
app:
        image: project/name:0.0.1
        volumes:
          - ./project:/usr/src/app
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        links:
         - "mongodb:mongodb"
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        command: ["npm", "start"]
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: I should have added this in the starting post, but I have tried both explicit linking, as you suggested, and implicit linking (since docker provides a DNS resolver which should resolve any hostnames to the proper address). I will change the question right now.

Comment: This is really strange behavior it may just be a bug, perhaps you should file an issue on docker-ce's repo on github